# What might happen if you post a local URL?

Tags: email

To show something in a forum you capture a page of an email service after logging in; but using MS Paint you erase the titles of the inbox as well as your name. Only the following information is shown

- company name
- the layout of the mailbox (its overall design) and their respective names
- (maybe) the URL post login

Can this ever pose a security risk to your company?

Comment: I would be more concerned about the content of the mails (in case some are visible)

Answer (score 0):

It is unlikely to pose a risk if you are using a popular software (Chrome, Outlook, etc.), do not have any evidence of options (such as a plugin that adds an icon or otherwise changes the interface), usernames are not real names, and the body contains no guarded information.

A local network URL that resolves to a service, by itself, is not easy to answer with the provided information, but if you are unsure, then you should not publish it to a globally reachable public forum.